# python validator with regex and value range

Tags: python, regex, qt

i want to combine two input validator for a QtWidgets.QLineEdit in one function. The problem is the value range validator (QDoubleValidator) doesn´t work and I get the following error:
Unexpected argument(s)Possible callees:QDoubleValidator(self: QDoubleValidator, parent: Union[QObject, QObject, None] = ...)QDoubleValidator(self: QDoubleValidator, bottom: float, top: float, decimals: int, parent: Union[QObject, QObject, None] = ...)

can someone help me to fix this please?

```
    def validator(field, e_min, e_max, e_komma=2):
    s_reg_ex = "([+-]|)[0-9]+\.[0-9]{" + str(e_komma) + "}"
    reg_ex = QRegExp(s_reg_ex)
    input_validator = QRegExpValidator(reg_ex, feld)
    field.setValidator(input_validator)
    field.setValidator(
        QtGui.QDoubleValidator(
            e_min, # bottom
            e_max, # top
            e_komma, # 2: decimals
            notation=QtGui.QDoubleValidator.StandardNotation
        )
    )
```

Comment: _"can you help me please?"_ Help you with what? What problems are you having? Please be specific about your issue. Visit the [help] and read [ask].

Comment: Thxs for your advice